# Drawing lines in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I'm working on an application in which Users can draw lines (with or without arrowheads).  Similar to PowerPoint or SnagIt, but on a 3D plane."

Basically I would like to be able to create some line types like in the attached draft:

[image: Line types draft]

I've seen the fat lines demo (https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lines_fat). But lines don't seem to change width when zooming, and they don't have perspective.

There is also this 3rd party library THREE.MeshLine (https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine) which has some nice features, even dashed lines animation, but before experimenting with it I would like to see what ThreeJS can do by itself.

1) Using ThreeJS Line is there a way to get:

- Size and perspective change depending on camera distance/zoom or angle.
- Dotted lines (Maybe extending DashedLineMaterial?).

2) Maybe there is a library other than THREE.MeshLine that does what I need?

Answer (score 1):

MeshLine is definitely what you want. Three.js's line implementations are all pixel based and don't really fit your needs. MeshLine is well written and performant, I use it myself for a similar purpose - it'll serve you well.